# How to get the background color of a cell with gspread (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

I would like to know how to find out what is the background color of a cell in my Google Spreadsheet. Is it possible to get using Gspread? Can you give me an easy example how to do it?

Answer (score -2):

> If you want to look only at the background color, you can remove the
>   value from this argument. The formula will look the following way
>   then: =COUNTA(valuesByColor("#b6d7a8","", B2:B40)). D2:D40 is the
>   range to check for colored cells. It looks at cells in column D in my
>   example.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/10/30/count-colored-cells-google-sheets/